# PDA for $\{a^nb^m \mid 0 < n \le m \le 3n\}$

Tags: automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I have to design a PDA that recognizes the language $\{a^nb^m \mid 0<n\leq m\leq3n\}$

I tried to partition the stack into 3 partitions with the first partition being the size of $n$ with character A, the second partition being the size of $2n$ with character B, and the third partition size of $n$ with character A.

I got stuck with this idea.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, the PDA consists of two phases.

During the first phase, the PDA reads $a$s. For each $a$ that it reads, it nondeterministically pushes either $A$, or $AA$, or $AAA$ to the stack.

During the second phase, the PDA reads $b$s, popping one $A$ per $b$ read. At the end, the stack needs to be empty.

Details left to you.